# Zend Paginator for Solr Search Result

Tags: zend-framework, solr, pagination

Is it possible to use Zend Paginator Class for Solr Search Result. If yes, can please explain how?

Following script successfully working with Database Results.

```
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($select);
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How are you returning your results? Using an array? (Perhaps like this: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolPHP#Solr.27s_PHP_response_format)

If so, you can create a paginator instance easily:

```
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator(new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Array($array))
or
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably stating the obvious here, but the key is to create a paginator adapter implementing `Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Interface`.

So, imitating how the paginator adapters for Zend_Db queries work, I assume that you have some kind of Solr query object that you can pass to the adapter on instantiation. Then in the adapter's `getItems($offset, $itemsPerPage)` method, you can modify the query object using those limit params, issue the query, and return the results.